# How to config the IIS to allow a site to create/read from Named Shared Memory?

Tags: iis, permissions, web, shared-memory

I am having strange problems with an application I need to use on a ASP.NET web site. 
This application is implementing a DB on the shared memory.

Now, I assume the IIS would not allow just any web-site to manipulate the shared memory. 
So, how do I configure the IIS to allow this web-site's unique operations, what permissions to set, etc?

Comment: Can you specify "shared memory"?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx

The dll that uses the shared memory is not our development, though so I am not certain about their implementation. However, I know they are using shared memory for IPC. the DB supports multiple processes and it does need a service or process (it is a dll that does not spawn threads, does not raise processes and does not do COM or other calls).

Comment: And you are writing you own Database?

Comment: No, I am using a DB dll (written by someone else, in an In-Memory DB) in my website. It works fine in a regular application. 

It sure looks like a permissions issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, there are several permission restrictions!, 
I suggest you read some articles on the subject and come back once you have a more specific question on sepcific permissions.

you can start with articles like this one:

Guidelines for Resolving IIS Permissions Problems - 
 *http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa954062.aspx*

Comment: I've worked it out tnx, nonetheless it's a good article for beginners I guess, I'll accept the answer ;)